# Update View on Realm Object Change

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I am updating an object in my Realm Database but I am having a hard time getting it to reload any of my views as a result. R.realm is a wrapper around realm. Both it and ActiveManager are working correctly as I can look at the results in Realm Studio and see them updating. How can I trigger a refresh when returning to the Items screen after toggling active on the Item screen? Is there anyway of just adding some kind of observer to the App entry point so that whenever the Realm database is changed for any reason it invalidates all the views and causes a refresh everywhere? I'm coming from a typescript/react background so I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the way swift is handling all this. Code below, I've truncated irrelevant parts for brevity

ManageView

```swift
struct ManageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: ItemsView(kind: ITEM_KIND.Area)) {
                    Text("Areas")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ItemsView(
                    kind: ITEM_KIND.Scheme
                )) {
                    Text("Schemes")
                }
```

ItemsView

```swift
struct ItemsView: View {
    @ObservedResults(Active.self) var active
    @State var showAddItemModal: Bool = false

    var kind: ITEM_KIND

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section("Current") {
                    ForEach(getCurrent(), id: \._id) { item in
                        VStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(item: item)) {
                                Text("\(item.title)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
...
   func getCurrent() -> Results<Item> {
        let currentPeriod = R.realm.getByKey(Period.self, key: ActiveManager.shared.getPeriod())!

        return R.realm.getWhere(Item.self) { item in item.kind == self.kind && item._id.in(currentPeriod.items) }
    }
```

ItemView

```swift
struct ItemView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var item: Item
    @State var isActive: Bool = false
    
    func viewWillAppear() {
        print("appear")
        isActive = ActiveManager.shared.getItems().contains(item._id)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                Toggle("Active", isOn: $isActive)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .onChange(of: isActive) { value in
                        if value {
                            ActiveManager.shared.addItem(item: item)
                        } else {
                            ActiveManager.shared.removeAllItems()
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You can add observers to the entire Realm, collections of objects or discreet objects. It's covered in the [Realm SwiftUI Quick Start](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/#views-and-observed-objects) where there are some code examples; in particular `@ObservedResults` and `@ObservedRealmObject` which "allows the View (that contains the object) to "know" when the object has changed"

Answer (score 0):

Will come back and post a more thorough solution at a later date but I couldn't get Realm's property wrappers to work so in the top Manage View I created some observable objects that contained the item arrays wrapped with the @Published wrapper and then some functions for updating the arrays. I then passed these observable objects down into Items View and again into Item view. Whenever I changed my item I then used one of the update array functions on the observable object to trigger a state refresh.

Comment: Realm does not have arrays so if you are using arrays to handle your Realm objects, it could be trouble! Realm objects are lazily loaded; thousands of objects have a very small memory footprint. If those are cast to arrays, that overrides that default behavior and all of the objects are loaded into memory, potentially overwhelming the device (crash!). Also, if a Results object is observed and one of the objects change, the app will be notified of that change - simply pass the object, change it and write it out. Results will automatically be updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
item.realm != nil
```

is a solution wich work fine for me, but it throws a warning. I call it after dismissing a sheet.